# Где здесь происходит кастинг (HashTest cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable)? в какой строке?

Tags: java, массивы

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class HashTest {

    private String str;

    public HashTest(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.str;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        HashTest h1 = new HashTest("2");        
        String s1 = new String("1");        

        Object arr[] = new Object[2];
        arr[0] = h1;
        arr[1] = s1;
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        for (Object o : arr) {
            System.out.print(o + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Каждая строчка кода отделяется 4-мя пробелами от начала строки.

Comment: В стек-трейсе, кстати, написан номер строки.

Comment: в `Arrays.sort(arr);`, для сортировки нужны сравнимые элементы

Answer (score 0):

В `Arrays.sort(arr)` элементы кастятся к интерфейсу `Comparable` для сравнения. Для того, чтобы избежать этой ошибки, нужно `HashSet` имплементить `Comparable`.

Comment: Если в `HashTest` заимплементить `Comparable`, то будет `ClassCastException`, так как массив с типом `Object`, а его содержимое не кастится одно к другому. В данном случае нужно для `Arrays.sort` вторым параметром передавать `Comparator` с `instanceOf` внутри например.

Comment: Вернее будет ClassCastException, когда вызовется compareTo(String s) у String, т.к. compareTo(String s) сравнивает со строкой

Comment: Хотя да, ты был прав